# why we are using javascript:void(0) in Angular code

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="loginlink">login</a>
```

I've seen such anchor tag's href property having `javascript:void(0)` value many times. I don't know what exactly that means.I saw this when working with angular 5. Why is `javascript:void(0)` used as a value for href property?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
javascript:void(0)
```

The snippet show above simply ignores the link "click." This can be done in a similar fashion by the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;">link</a>
```

Comment: This answer doesn't really define why people are using `javascript:void(0)`. The simple answer is that javascript via a framework such as Angular, React, or Vue usually have click handlers that don't properly address the browser wanting an `href`. The browser won't treat the link as a clickable link unless it has the `href`. Therefore, people started putting `href="<please for the love of...>"`, and substituting it rather than changing CSS etc. The reason people DON'T want to use a `#` is because it's treated AS A ROUTING MECHANISM in these, not just a 'scroll here!' on the same page link...

Comment: Alternatively use `onclick="event.preventDefault()"`